# include_once(): Failed opening

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm working on MVC and I want to add these components to use but get an error when I call in.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i think your path is wrong, try to load ` ../../partials/header.php`

Comment: I tried it but I still couldn't